# "mean" within "by" throwing warning in R

Tags: r

I was trying to get group wise mean using **by** function as per following:

```
by(iris[,1:4],iris$Species,mean)
```

but i am getting  **warnings:**

```
iris$Species: setosa
[1] NA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] NA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

However all of below commands works fine, i wonder why mean is not working correctly if i provide,`iris[,1:4]` as first argument in **by** function.

```
 by(iris[,1:4],iris$Species,summary)
 by(iris[,1],iris$Species,mean)
 aggregate(iris[,1:4],list(iris$Species),mean)
```

Also after some google , i found this [link](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) and it seems `by(iris[,1:4],iris$Species,mean)` command should work.

I am unable to find where i am committing mistake. Any help for anyone is much appreciated.

I am using inbuilt **iris** data for demo.

R version - 3.0.2 on windows (32 bit)

Thanks

Comment: How could you add a ifelse(is.numeric, mean, NA) there?.

I can't get to pass columns instead of the whole data.frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to calculate the mean values of the columns, you have to use `colMeans`:

```
> by(iris[1:4], iris$Species, colMeans)

iris$Species: setosa
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       5.006        3.428        1.462        0.246 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: versicolor
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       5.936        2.770        4.260        1.326 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
iris$Species: virginica
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       6.588        2.974        5.552        2.026
```

---

*Update*:

By the way: You can use `mean` if you use `aggregate` instead of `by`:

```
> aggregate(iris[1:4], list(iris$Species), mean)

     Group.1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Comment: +1 , thanks very much, but i was wondering,if it so to use colmeans instead of mean, why the link (which i posted) uses mean, is it that earlier version of R works with mean?

Comment: @PradeepKumar Long time ago, the function `mean` was similar to `colMeans` when applied to a data frame. Now, you have to use `colMeans`.

Comment: @PradeepKumar I added another solution with `mean`.

Comment: I understood this solution completely, but one question i am still wondering is, why this works- by(iris[,1],iris$Species,mean) ?

Comment: @PradeepKumar The command `by(iris[,1],iris$Species,mean)` works because `iris[,1]` does not return a data frame, but a vector. You will receive warning messages if you use `by(iris[1],iris$Species,mean)` because `iris[1]` returns a one-column data frame.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Take a look at the `drop` argument to `[` for some further clarity, as described in `? Extract`.

Answer (score 2):

It's plausible that you want something like:

```
> sapply(iris[,1:4],by,iris$Species,mean)
           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
setosa            5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
virginica         6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

Or:

```
> lapply(iris[,1:4],by,iris$Species,mean)
$Sepal.Length
iris$Species: setosa
[1] 5.006
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] 5.936
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] 6.588

$Sepal.Width
iris$Species: setosa
[1] 3.428
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] 2.77
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] 2.974

$Petal.Length
iris$Species: setosa
[1] 1.462
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] 4.26
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] 5.552

$Petal.Width
iris$Species: setosa
[1] 0.246
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: versicolor
[1] 1.326
------------------------------------------------------------ 
iris$Species: virginica
[1] 2.026
```